# Using ChromeDriver without Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I want to launch and operate Chrome with ChromeDriver, without Selenium.
I knew that Selenium is using webdriver to control browser. It seems like ChromeDriver is just launch a local http server and a connection of remote develop tool to Chrome. Selenium just a client to send http request the server.
I'd like to send http request directly to ChromeDriver to control Chrome. Is that possible? Anyone can show me how to implement that?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can send CDP commands directly, see [the documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), there are also many small libraries that provide a minimal wrapper for CDP commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But Webdriver API seem different (may a part of) Chrome DevTools Protocol. Seem like ChromeDriver is useless for CDP. Am I right?

Comment: CDP is the underlying API used by ChromeDriver internally, AFAIK.